# How to put my website containing java on the web

Tags: java, eclipse, html

I've made a dynamic web project in eclipse, and now I would like to put it on the web. Usually I'd just put the files on the web server, and it would run on my webpage, but this doesn't work when there's java involved.

Can anyone walk me through how to put a dynamic web project from eclipse on a real web server? I'm a complete newbie.

Comment: You need an application server. Most probably you have an Apache server. Look at Tomcat, or Jetty, Glassfish

Comment: I already use tomcat on my computer when developing. Should I install it on my web server as well?

Comment: @Cathrine if you don't own your own web server that you can install Java (JRE) on, then you need to verify if your hosted server has this capabilities - most don't.